# What does arr++ mean in a function "int f(int arr[])"?

Tags: c++, arrays, post-increment, function-parameter

I was looking at this code and understood pretty much all of it except one thing:
what does `Arr1++` means?

What does it do to the array? since `Arr1` is not just a normal variable like `int`..

```
bool theSameElements(int Arr1[], int Arr2[], int size)
{
    int temp;
    if (size == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (Arr1[0] == Arr2[i])
        {
            temp = Arr2[i];
            Arr2[i] = Arr2[0];
            Arr2[0] = temp;
            Arr1++;
            Arr2++;
            return theSameElements(Arr1, Arr2, size - 1);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Despite being declared as `int Arr1[]`, `Arr1` is a pointer to int, so the code is incrementing the pointer.

Comment: Can we retag as C?

Comment: @Amr  That is completely wrong.

Comment: Worthwhile reading: [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)

Comment: Incrementing the address. An array name is just a pointer to its first element `arr[0]` thus to move to the next element you either increment the address or use `index`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any [array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array) passed as function parameter is implicitly converted / *decays* to a [pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer) of type `int*`. Now the `Arr1` is a pointer pointing to the first array element namely `Arr1[0]`. This is known as the [Array-to-pointer decay](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array#Array-to-pointer_decay). Applying the [post-increment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec):

```
Arr1++;
```

**increments** the pointer value by the size of the data it points to so now it points to the second array element `Arr1[1]`.

That being said you should prefer [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) to raw arrays and [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) to raw pointers.

Comment: There's no decaying going on here. The result of array-to-pointer decaying is an rvalue, and `++` requires an lvalue.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/MwLWhX for what happens when actual array-to-pointer decaying happens.

Comment: Thanks. If I understood it right- when I do arr++; it means that the "new" arr[0] is actually arr[1] or ?

Comment: As said, the parameter `Arr1` **is not** an array, but a pointer. (The argument passed *might* be, and will then decay to a pointer.) Never confuse the two, even if the syntax can be deceptive.

Comment: I understand.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

So what you need to know is that `Arr`, in this case, is the pointer to the array. So when you do `Arr++` you are basically incrementing the pointer to this array.

Answer (score 1):

Function parameters which appear to have array type, in fact have pointer type. `int foo[3]` and `int foo[]`, in the context of a function parameter list (and *only* in that context), are exactly the same as `int* foo`. Because of this, you can do things to them that you wouldn't ordinarily be able to do to arrays, such as reassign their values.